# Not all code paths return a value when using Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, task

So I have this function where I have a return in all `if-else` but still getting the Compilation error:

> not all code paths return a value

```
public async Task<bool> DeletePost(string update_id, string authId)
{
    if (Utility.NetworkStatus.HasInternetAccess)
    {
        await APIs.DeletePost.DeletePostAPI(update_id, authId).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                if (t.Result != null)
                {
                    return t.Result.status == 200;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                    //empty result, API failed
                    //not implemented
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
                //task failed 
                //not implemented
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        //no network
        //not implemented
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return await APIs.DeletePost.DeletePostAPI` and `return false` at the end of the method

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You don't return the result of the continuation of `DeletePostAPI`:

```
public async Task<bool> DeletePost(string update_id, string authId)
{
    if (Utility.NetworkStatus.HasInternetAccess)
    {
        return await APIs.DeletePost.DeletePostAPI(update_id, authId).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                if (t.Result != null)
                {
                    return t.Result.status == 200;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                    //empty result, API failed
                    //not implemented
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
                //task failed 
                //not implemented
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        //no network
        //not implemented
    }
}
```

Comment: So when does this new return executes? Considering the flow of my function

Comment: @Rishabh876 After the `DeletePostAPI` completes, and its continuation completes the  value you return from the continuation is returned from `DeletePost`

Comment: Oh Damn, now I got it. That was so silly of me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code becomes a lot simpler if you remove `ContinueWith` completely and just use the more modern `await` instead:

```
public async Task<bool> DeletePost(string update_id, string authId)
{
  if (Utility.NetworkStatus.HasInternetAccess)
  {
    try
    {
      var result = await APIs.DeletePost.DeletePostAPI(update_id, authId);
      if (result != null)
      {
        return result.status == 200;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
        //empty result, API failed
        //not implemented
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      return false;
      //task failed 
      //not implemented
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
    //no network
    //not implemented
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the return value of your await.  So:

```
bool result = await APIs.DeletePost.DeletePostAPI(update_id, authId).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                    {
                        if (t.Result != null)
                        {
                            return t.Result.status == 200;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                            //empty result, API failed
                            //not implemented
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                        //task failed 
                        //not implemented
                    }
                });
return result;
```